# Code studio (editor) пули для файлов конфигурации

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fedora

Code studio иногда в настройках запрашивает прописать пути для собственных файлов конфигурации. Так вот я не могу понять по какому пути они будут искаться. Пробовал разное, но срабатывает только потный путь к файлу. Не работает такое

```
$HOME/.config/lua_format.json
~/.config/lua_format.json
/home/ekkl/.config/lua_format.json # Only this work's
```

Закидывал файл в

```
 $HOME/.config/Code
 $HOME/.config/Code/User
```

Все без толку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в майрософте не очень любят переменные окружения. смирись

Comment: @eri, так полный путь единственный выход? Подход так себе...